# Install Ubuntu 20.04 from usb fails, error -32 and error -110

Tags: boot, usb

I am trying to install Ubuntu 20.04 on a USB drive I created on another Ubuntu device. I have successfully used this USB drive to install Ubuntu 20.04 on my laptop. I am now trying to use it to install Ubuntu 20.04 on my desktop.

When I boot from the USB drive, I get the following errors:

```
Initramfs unpacking failed: Decoding failed
usb 2-2: device descriptor read/64, error -32
usb 2-2: device descriptor read/64, error -32
usb 2-2: device descriptor read/64, error -32
usb 2-2: device descriptor read/64, error -32
usb 2-2: device not accepting address 5, error -32
usb 2-2: device not accepting address 6, error -32
usb usb2-port2: unable to enumerate USB device    
usb 5-1: device descriptor read/64, error -110
usb 5-1: device descriptor read/64, error -110
usb 5-1: device descriptor read/64, error -110
usb 5-1: device descriptor read/64, error -110
usb 5-1: device not accepting address 4, error -110
usb 5-1: device not accepting address 5, error -110
usb usb5-port1: unable to enumerate USB device
usb 5-2: device descriptor read/64, error -32
usb 5-2: device descriptor read/64, error -32
usb 5-2: device descriptor read/64, error -32
usb 5-2: device descriptor read/64, error -32
usb 5-2: device not accepting address 8, error -32
usb 5-2: device not accepting address 9, error -32
usb usb5-port2: unable to enumerate USB device
usb 5-3: device descriptor read/64, error -32
usb 5-3: device descriptor read/64, error -32
usb 5-3: device descriptor read/64, error -32
usb 5-3: device descriptor read/64, error -32
usb 5-3: device not accepting address 12, error -32
usb 5-3: device not accepting address 13, error -32
usb usb5-port3: unable to enumerate USB device
usb 5-4: device descriptor read/64, error -32
usb 5-4: device descriptor read/64, error -32
usb 5-4: device descriptor read/64, error -32
usb 5-4: device descriptor read/64, error -32
usb 5-4: device not accepting address 16, error -32
usb 5-4: device not accepting address 17, error -32
usb usb5-port4: unable to enumerate USB device
Unable to find a medium container a live file system
Attempt interactive netboot from a URL?
yes no (default yes):
```

At some point during this process my screen shows the name of my motherboard and then UBUNTU underneath, with a rotating wheel.

Anyone have any idea what is going on? Based on other things I've read, I am afraid my motherboard is having problems providing power to the USB port. But, the USB port seems to work fine when I boot into Ubuntu and interact with it there.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED: This is a bug with Gigabyte motherboards and is not unique to Ubuntu: in fact it appears to occur for all 64-bit OS installs.

More info in:

- [[SOLVED] Install Woes [unable to enumerate USB device]](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=231515)
- [GIGABYTE GA-970A-DS3 motherboard not working with 64 bit kernel](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2111223&page=2&s=f23d016d9eacc001cefd713b518abe50)

Answer (score 0):

As stated, it is a motherboard BIOS problem.

However, I had the same issue with my Gigabyte GA-970A-D3 model and was able to find a fix for the USB read error via this Arch forum https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=159467. Here they discuss that it was the IOMMU setting that was disabled in the BIOS that was causing the USB read issue. Once I set my IOMMU setting to enabled it booted to my USB without problem.